# Setting Client values to ColdFusion functions using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I'm looking for a way to set client variables in a cfc with ajax. I am creating a simple message board script using html5 and ajax. The script will grab the UID of the device using jQuery and then compare the UID to a database to see if the user exists. If the user exists I then need this data stored in Client or Session scopes to use this information again.

I have no clue where to begin with this. I tried storing the data in jQuery but you cannot save ajax variables as global variables securely. I also attempted to see if I can create these scopes with simple remote functions but you cannot share these scopes within the same cfcomponent.

Any ideas?

Comment: have it call a cfc which stores the values in client or session

Comment: Remember the separation of duties - jQuery/AJAX is run on the client - ColdFusion/session is run on the server. _I tried storing the data in jQuery_ jQuery (the client) does not know anything about the ColdFusion server's session. The ColdFusion server is able to maintain sessions when you use jQuery/AJAX calls. So you can pass values to the ColdFusion cfc via an AJAX call and then in your cfc store the required values into the session scope.

Comment: @MattBusche when I tried that it didn't work. Silly me forgot to enable to damn client scope

Comment: Food for thought... http://www.dopefly.com/pages/ColdFusionClientVariablesFinalNail.cfm I wouldn't recommend using client variables at all.

Comment: @SeanCoyne what would you recommend? sessions?

Comment: or, look at sessionStorage/localStorage on the browser. or jQuery lets you intercept ALL ajax calls so you could inject your device UID into all ajax requests as an extra parameter/header. That way the server doesn't need to store the ID at all. I'd avoid client scope too, it has problems and you'll be wanting to avoid it if at all possible.